# How to verify this property of homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, group-homomorphism, injective-module

While studying a result( Lemma 3.11) on page 196 of Thomas Hunger Ford I have a question whose image I am adding.

Image:[image]

Question: I am not able to prove g(ab)= g(a) g(b) property of group homomorphism in line 4 of proof .

Can anyone please tell how to do that?

Edit 1: Similarly in last line of above image I am not getting:$h(r) xy = h(r) (x) h(r) (y) $ . ( I am getting $\bar g(xyr)= \bar g (xr) \bar g(yr) $ , which are not equal).

So, how should I proceed?

Edit 2:

In third line of proof  I have similar problem ie I am unable to prove $\bar f(rg) = r\bar f(g) $ as I don't know how frg can be proved equal to rfg?

[image]

Comment: Please replace the embedded images of text by actual text using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting of formulas. Two of your images aren't properly embedded into the question anyway.

Comment: @Christoph I have edited it. Hope it's fine now!!

Comment: The question still contains two large portions of text as images and is thus not accessible for users with screen readers etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused with the operation. If $L$ is an ideal then it is a group with respect to addition, not with respect to multiplication. Similarly, Hom$_Z(R,J)$ is a group with respect to function addition, i.e $(f_1+f_2)(r)=f_1(r)+f_2(r)$. So what you actually have to prove is $g(a+b)=g(a)+g(b)$. And this is indeed true, because:

$g(a+b)=f(a+b)(1_R)=[f(a)+f(b)](1_R)=f(a)(1_R)+f(b)(1_R)=g(a)+g(b)$

Where $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ is true because $f$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. I have understood what mistake I was making in 1st and 2nd but 3rd of homomorphism( which is given in Edit 2) is still not clear to me. Can you please explain that also?

Comment: Can you please explain 3rd homomorphism if you got some spare time for it?

Comment: @Tim Sure. We have to show that $\overline{f}(rg)=r\overline{f}(g)$. Equivalently, we want to show that $f\circ (rg)=r\times (f\circ g)$. So let any $a\in R$. We have $f\circ (rg)(a)=f[(rg)(a)]=f[rg(a)]=rf[g(a)]=r\times (f\circ g)(a)$. We used the fact that $f$ is a homomorphism, this is why $f[r g(a)]=rf[g(a)]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!