# A question in proof of a part of a theorem in Chapter Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

While studying abstract algebra from Thomas Hungerford I am unable to understand reasoning behind this particular argument in the theorem $4.8$ on page-$203$.

It's image:

[image]

Question is in highlighted part: How does author wrote $fs(\phi(a)) = f(\phi(a) ) s $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the definition of "scalar" multiplication in Hom$_R(A',B)$. The homomorphism $fs$ is defined by $(fs)(b)=(f(b))s$ for all $b\in A'$. That's an intuitive definition if you think about it, you multiply the function $f$ by the scalar $s$ from the right side.

Comment: can you also answer this question which is related to question you've answered if you have some time to spare. I shall be really thankful to you!!https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808239/how-to-verify-this-property-of-homomorphism

Comment: @Tim I wrote an answer there, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much!!